# Verificação de tabela sempre igual

Tags: php

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
<?PHP
$status = mysqli_query($connecta, "SELECT `online` FROM `char` WHERE `name`='[ADM] koda'");
$resultado = mysqli_num_rows($status);

echo '
<tr align="center" id="player">

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">posicao</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">name</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">guilda</td>';
if($resultado == 0) { 
echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">off</td></tr>';
}
if ($resultado == 1) {
echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">on</td></tr>';
}
  ?>
```

Problema:
Mesmo com a query com o valor na database em 0, ele continua mostrando o echo 'on'.
A query no SQL retorna **corretamente**,o problema é de **lógica** no **IF**.
Alguém conhece alguma solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função **[mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)** retorna o número de registros da consulta, e não o campo do select.

Você precisa verificar se o **resultado** da consulta é igual a 0:

```
$status = mysqli_query($connecta, "SELECT `online` FROM `char` WHERE `name`='[ADM] koda'");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($status);
// ...
if ($resultado['online'] == 0) {

}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa, só para ilustrar o uso do num_rows:

```
<?PHP
   $status = mysqli_query($connecta,
      "SELECT `online` FROM `char` WHERE `name`='[ADM] koda' AND `online` = 1");
   $resultado = mysqli_num_rows($status);
```

Neste caso, em vez de saber o STATUS do usuário, basta acrescentar a clausula `online = 1` para ver se existe algum registro com essa condição ou não.

Notas:

- Eu ainda prefiro o caminho da resposta do @luciorubens.
- Com MYSQLI_USE_RESULT no 2o parametro do `mysqli_query` o resultado pode dar problemas. O ideal é MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT

Comment: Ah, ótima alternativa! `+1`